# Consuming a php soap web service with excel2007

Tags: php, web-services, soap, excel-2007

I'm trying to figure out how to connect Excel 2007 to php5 based web services.
I found [this pretty interessting article on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/hovsep/archive/2007/07/11/excel-2007-how-to-connect-to-and-import-data-from-an-xml-web-service.aspx). Ok, so it seems to be
doable. Now, php5 soap services don't accept parameters in url form, so a RESTesque call like

```
http://domain.org/service.php?getme=something
```

won't work out since there are soap request envelopes to be transfered...
Does anyone have experiences / hints for me on this topic?

tia

K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like excel just does simple get requests.  You will need to write a non-soap interface to your php web service.

Comment: that's what I figured too. Finally I wrote a REST wrapper around my SOAP service in order to get it going...